# Eclipse equivalent of "Open folder in windows explorer"

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010

There's a handy feature in Visual Studio where you can "Open folder in windows explorer" when selecting a project, and that will open the folder in which the project and source files are stored.

Is there an equivalent feature of eclipse? I've yet to find a way to even locate a project or source file on disk directly from the eclipse project explorer.

Comment: I don't think so but with the navigator you can view, copy and delete as in the windows explorer.

Comment: I am aware that, I have come across many situations where those functions were not enough and I had to access a file directly in windows explorer.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few third-party plugins that provide this kind of feature. The one I currently use is called EasyShell. You can easily install it by opening the Eclipse Marketplace (under the *Help* menu) and search for EasyShell.